# SQLITE Summary by Sequence

Tags: sqlite, sum, sequence

I have a table where name, start time and duration.
I need a query that will give me the last 5 names, start time and duration. When if there is a sequence of several names - should get the beginning of the sequence, and its overall continuation.
If there are several sequences of the same name - should only get the last one.

for example:

| name | start_time | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 79431 | 70 |
| a | 79420 | 11 |
| a | 79415 | 5 |
| b | 79413 | 1 |
| c | 79300 | 112 |
| c | 79298 | 2 |
| b | 79296 | 2 |
| c | 79288 | 6 |
| c | 79284 | 3 |
| c | 79278 | 347 |
| d | 78400 | 200 |
| d | 77764 | 636 |
| e | 77759 | 4 |
| d | 77741 | 17 |
| f | 77700 | 7 |
| a | 77642 | 10 |

Should be:

| name seq | start_time seq | duration seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 79415 | 86 |
| b | 79413 | 1 |
| c | 79298 | 114 |
| d | 77764 | 836 |
| e | 77759 | 4 |

Would appreciate help!
Thank you

Comment: What mean `last 5 names` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to definir when we start a new sequence with the same name.
I have 2 queries, one takes all occurences of a name as one sequence. The other keeps them together if they follow in the table.

> ```
> create table table_name(
> name varchar(10),
> start_time int,
> duration int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into table_name values
> ('a',79431,70),
> ('a',79420,11),
> ('a',79415,5),
> ('b',79413,1),
> ('c',79300,112),
> ('c',79298,2),
> ('b',79296,2),
> ('c',79288,6),
> ('c',79284,3),
> ('c',79278,347),
> ('d',78400,200),
> ('d',77764,636),
> ('e',77759,4),
> ('d',77741,17),
> ('f',77700,7),
> ('a',77642,10);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select
>   t.name,
>   min(start_time) beginning,
>   sum(duration) duration
> from table_name t
> join
> (select distinct name
> from table_name
> order by start_time desc
> limit 5) n
> on t.name = n.name
> group by t.name;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | beginning | duration
> :--- | --------: | -------:
> a    |     77642 |       96
> b    |     79296 |        3
> c    |     79278 |      470
> d    |     77741 |      853
> e    |     77759 |        4
> ```

> ```
> select
> name,
> min(start_time) beginning,
> sum(duration) duration
> from
> (select 
>   name,
>   start_time,
>   duration,
>   row_number() over(order by start_time) rn,
>   row_number() over(order by start_time desc)
>    - row_number() over(partition by name order by start_time desc) as group_number
> from table_name) t
> group by name,group_number
> order by group_number
> limit 5;
> ```

> ```
> name | beginning | duration
> :--- | --------: | -------:
> a    |     79415 |       86
> b    |     79413 |        1
> c    |     79298 |      114
> b    |     79296 |        2
> c    |     79278 |      356
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c4172fb28247e607d3c672e7699901a8)*